# Is there a way to change the place where android menu appears

Tags: java, android

normally when the menu button is pressed , the menu appears from the center bottom of the screen. Is there a way to make it appear from sides.

Comment: You might consider using a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Answer (score 2):

On Android 3.0 and higher, items from the options menu are presented by the **action bar** which is **standard way** to provide access to menus and normally menus appears from top right corner. You should go through this once:

[Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)